# Select last 3 rows from database order by id ASC

Tags: php, mysql, select

how can i select last 3 rows from users table and then order it by id ascending?

for example :

```
id    |    username    |    password

1     |    user1       |    pass1

2     |    user2       |    pass2

3     |    user3       |    pass3

4     |    user4       |    pass4

5     |    user5       |    pass5
```

i want to select user5, user4 and user3 then order it by id **ASCENDING**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this...

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 3
) sub
ORDER BY id ASC
```

Comment: can you explain me what is the sub?

Comment: actually sub is the name of table?

Comment: no...its just a class...add this code to ur query and change table to the name of ur table...